# Sort List / Vector of any Object by any member's field?

Tags: java, android, stack-overflow

This has been asked a thousand times, but all of answers I've seen do not work on a passed Object, they are always **hard coded to which Object and which field**. I'm looking for a way to sort a List / Vector of  based on a string field. I don't mind if it uses Reflection or Voodoo magic.

The method I've written results in a **StackOverFlowError** (pun intended!).

I call my method as follows:

```
StandardComparator.sort("distance",Vector<?>)StaticItems.LocationList,Item.SingleLocation.class);
```

StandardComparator class is defined as such:

```
public class StandardComparator {   
    public static void sort(final String field, Vector<?> locationList, final Class typeOfObject){
        Collections.sort(locationList, new Comparator<Object>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Object object1, Object object2) {
                try {
                    return this.compare(typeOfObject.getField(field),typeOfObject.getField(field));
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return 0;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(22828): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
E/AndroidRuntime(22828): java.lang.StackOverflowError
E/AndroidRuntime(22828):        at java.lang.reflect.Field.<init>(Field.java:89)
E/AndroidRuntime(22828):        at java.lang.reflect.Field.<init>(Field.java:81)
E/AndroidRuntime(22828):        at java.lang.reflect.ReflectionAccessImpl.clone(ReflectionAccessImpl.java:42)
E/AndroidRuntime(22828):        at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:870)
E/AndroidRuntime(22828):        at com.AtClass.Extras.StandardComparator$1.compare(StandardComparator.java:24)
```

A SingleLocation object:

```
public class SingleLocation {
        int id;
        public String deviceId;
        public String title;
        public String message;
        public double latCoords;
        public double lngCoords;
        public String locSeen;
        public Bitmap icon;
        public double distance;
        public String distanceString;

        public SingleLocation(String id, String deviceId, String title, String message, String latCoords, String lngCoords, String locSeen){
            this.id = Integer.valueOf(id);
            this.deviceId = deviceId;
            this.title = title;
            this.message = message;
            this.latCoords = Double.valueOf(latCoords);
            this.lngCoords = Double.valueOf(lngCoords);
            this.locSeen = locSeen;
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you want to it behave in your required way, you need add some more stuff in compare() method. calling just super class method won't work(Since its default behavior).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that will work on any Comparable field. You'd have to add special handling for primitive types and non-Comparables:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.*;

public class ReflectionBasedComparator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Foo> foos = Arrays.asList(new Foo("a", "z"), new Foo("z", "a"), new Foo("n", "n"));
        Collections.sort(foos, new ReflectiveComparator("s"));
        System.out.println(foos);
        Collections.sort(foos, new ReflectiveComparator("t"));
        System.out.println(foos);
    }

    static class Foo {
        private String s;
        private String t;

        public Foo(String s, String t) {
            this.s = s;
            this.t = t;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Foo{" +
                           "s='" + s + '\'' +
                           ", t='" + t + '\'' +
                           '}';
        }
    }

    private static class ReflectiveComparator implements Comparator<Object> {
        private String fieldName;

        public ReflectiveComparator(String fieldName) {
            this.fieldName = fieldName;
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            try {
                Field field = o1.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
                if (!Comparable.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
                    System.out.println(field.getType());
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Field not Comparable: " + field);
                }
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Comparable o1FieldValue = (Comparable) field.get(o1);
                Comparable o2FieldValue = (Comparable) field.get(o2);
                return o1FieldValue.compareTo(o2FieldValue);
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Field doesn't exist", e);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Field inaccessible", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Ryan. The code does work but inadvertently throws an IllegalStateException when sorting by double.

Comment: It's not inadvertent. That's a primitive value that you'll have to add support for.

Answer (score 1):

You are just calling your own method, causing the stack overflow. Since you know the fields are `String`'s, just cast them to `String` and use its `compareTo()` method.

Comment: Not all the fields in Item.SingleLocation are strings. Its a mix of String, double and int.

Comment: In that case there is no easy way to do this. double and int are primitives, so you should have some logic to determine the type and compare accordingly. You can have a look at Apache Commons Lang's CompareToBuilder if you need a more general solution: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.0/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/CompareToBuilder.html

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your compare method with this:

```
return typeOfObject.getField(field).get(object1).compareTo(typeOfObject.getField(field).get(object2));
```

and cater for exceptions (field not found, null pointer, ...).

Comment: The Field.get(Object object) method returns the value of the field represented by this object. More info [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, however the method does not achieve the desired results as it does not compile.

The method compareTo(Object) is undefined for the type Object

Comment: Yes, you're right. If you know what you're comparing is a Comparable you can cast. Or you can write another method just to compare the values of objects you pass to it.

Answer (score 0):

The [Bean Comparator](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/23/bean-comparator/) should work.

Comment: Yes but how to implement it? It does not seem like it accepts a list.

Comment: @Kevin, what do you mean it doesn't accept a List? You invoke it the same why you do any sort by using Collections.sort(List, theBeanComparator). And it also works on primitives. The code looks a little more complicated because it provide more features. The difference is that this Comparator needs you to implement "get" accessor methods for the fields you want to compare, which is a good design for any bean anyway because you shouldn't use public accessor on fields.